# Is there a way to pass attributes to Vue JS computed getter/setter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am trying to use computed property to bind my input fields with the Vuex Store.
So I have `Data Streams` and each of them have specific `input fields`, they aren't fixed but managed from the admin section of the application, and I have to provide to the users functionality that user will select specific data stream and then inputs will be shown as received from the API.

I have tried to achieve that but here is my blocker. Computed properties (getters) cannot receive attributes so I cannot tell the vuex getter which data to return.

Please find bellow the code I have used, Is there some other way to achieve the same functionality?

I am using the next versions:

- vue - 2.6.1
- vuex - 3.6.2
- vuetify - 2.5.6

##### Vue JS Component - Input fields

```
<v-text-field
    :key="input_index"
    v-model="data_stream_inputs[ds_index][input_index]"
    :label="input.name"
    :placeholder="input.placeholder"
></v-text-field>
```

##### Computed properties (not working properly)

```
computed: {
    data_stream_inputs: {
        get() {
            return this.$store.getters['ActivateAudienceStore/getDataStreamInputByIndex'],
        set(value) {
            this.$store.commit('ActivateAudienceStore/SET_DATASTREAM_INPUT_BY_INDEX', value)
        }
    }
}
```

##### Getter

```
export const getDataStreamInputByIndex = (state) => (payload) => {
    return state.data_delivery.datastreams[payload.data_stream].inputs[payload.index]
}
```

Comment: Which Vue version is it? Is it Vuetify? Please, update the question with relevant details

Comment: @EstusFlask sorry for missing the details. I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data_stream_inputs` should be a function in order to receive arguments and be used like `data_stream_inputs({ index: index1 })[index2]`, this doesn't play well with a writable computed.

`v-model` doesn't have to be used where it's not straightforward, it can be desugared, e.g. in Vue 2:

```
<v-text-field
    :value="$store.getters['someGetter']({ index: index1 })[index2]"
    @update:value="$store.commit('someMutation', $event)"
    ...
```

Comment: I made it with :value & change instead of update and it work like expected!

Thanks for reviewing the question in details and providing straight forward answer!